# Publish Vue using Development/Test config

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've looked and tried tons of different commands to get this to work, and nothing seems to do the trick. 
I'm trying to get this setup so I can use a pipeline in Azure for a specific environment using settings in the environment specific config.

I've using vue cli 4.4.4. My Layout looks like this :

[image]

I've tried

```
vue build --mode development
vue-cli-service build --mode development
npm run build --development
npm run build -- --mode development
```

If they end up working, all they do is build in production anyway..

[image]

I'm running out commands. I would like it to use the dev.env.js config, it works fine in development when I use:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: Does your `build.js` file call the vue-cli-service?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out somewhat.

I can run :

```
npm run build --mode development
```

I had to modify the build.js and webpack.prod.config.js files to below:

build.js (grab the command 'development' from process.argv[2])

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
var webconfigEnv = "production"

switch (process.argv[2] || 'production') {
  case "development":
    webconfigEnv = "dev"
    break;
  case "test":
    webconfigEnv = "dev"
  default:
    break;
}

const ora = require('ora')
const rm = require('rimraf')
const path = require('path')
const chalk = require('chalk')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')


const spinner = ora('building for '+ webconfigEnv +'...')
spinner.start()
```

webpack.prod.conf.js  (switch which config it is using from env in process.argv[2])

```
var webconfigEnv = "prod"

switch (process.argv[2] || 'production') {
  case "development":
    webconfigEnv = "dev"
    break;
  case "test":
    webconfigEnv = "dev"
  default:
    break;
}

const env = require('../config/'+webconfigEnv+'.env')
console.log('Using config -- ../config/'+webconfigEnv+'.env');
```